# Best Way to Create Image Gallery

Tags: drupal-7

Please provide any examples or links which clearly explaining to create simple image gallery in Drupal 7.

Actually the image gallery should be in Thumb Nail Image with 4 images per row.

It should be categorized with simple menu. 
If there is sub category, then there should be drop down menus.

Finally the gallery should be with pagination links.

I've tried with taxamony, but it not clear display as expected in front end.

Please provide the better way either thru code or any modules available.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do an image gallery. If something like [galleria](http://galleria.io/) is what you are looking for you can do it very easily just by using an image field and drupal galleria module.

But in your case, you will have to use [views](https://drupal.org/project/views). In that pull out the images you want, choose the
display as grid. Set the no. of columns to 4. Link to the original image. Then you can use the 
[Lightbox](https://drupal.org/node/735424) module to open them in a lightbox, if you want one.

For pagination you can use the default views pagination settings.

Comment: Can we implement it dynamic using galleria? I mean thru database.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://rootexplanation.wordpress.com/) might help you. Check out.